# removing quotations and brackets from an array when printing (cannot use puts)

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
[1] pry(main)> ip = ["123.456.789.666"]
=> ["123.456.789.666"]

[2] pry(main)> p ip
["123.456.789.666"]
=> ["123.456.789.666"]
```

How do I get it so that it comes out 123.456.789.666? The end goal is to take whatever IP is in my array to ping with. The ping fails because it's doing ping "123.456.789.666".

Comment: use puts.......

Comment: You have an array.  If you want one element of the array, you index into the array.

Comment: if i index to ip[0] I'd still get the quotations.

Comment: how do you execute ping?

Comment: I'm first using the 'resolv' gem to get the IP then using the 'net/ping' gem do the ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the IP only as a string or IPAddr object (but in general it will be a string for `net/ping` gem). Looks like there are some problems with this gem when host specified as an IP.

If you need to check the availability of a server - use system `ping`:

```
#5 - number of retry, ip[0] - your ip from the array
`ping -q -c 5 #{ip[0]}`
'All is OK' if $?.exitstatus == 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around. It's not as clean but it at least allows me to do what I need.